# How to change the path of image in Node.js with Firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a system where new clients make account requests. They create their profile and they upload their profile picture in a temporary path.

When I accept the request manually, I would like to move the file from `requests/{requestID}/profileImage.jpg` to `userFiles/{userID}/profileImage.jpg` with a cloud function

I searched and it seems it's not possible to cut and paste a file. However, I guess it's possible to copy the image and the delete the old one.

I know how to delete a file, but I don't know **how to take the temporary file and copy it to a new destination**. Do you have any idea?

- From the URL?
- Do I have to convert the image URL to base64 in order to re-upload it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, it was possible, and it's pretty easy. This is the doc https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#storage-rename-object-nodejs, and here is the code:

```
async function moveFile(oldEntirePath, newEntirePath) {
  var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

  return bucket.file(oldEntirePath).move(newEntirePath)
  .then(resp => {

    let bucketPart = resp[1].resource.bucket
    let namePart = resp[0].id
    let tokenPart = resp[1].resource.metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens

    const url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/"+ bucketPart +"/o/"+ namePart +"?alt=media&token=" + tokenPart
    console.log(`Image url = ${url}`)
    return url

  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(`Unable to upload image ${err}`)
  })
}
```

Comment: how to this in the client side code?